# Code for joystick on sense hat

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, joystick

I just got a sense hat for Christmas, and I am working through the following website: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-the-sense-hat. When doing the joystick part of the website, i typed in this code:

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
sense = SenseHat()
while True:
    for event in sense.stick.get_events():
        print(event.direction, event.action)
```

and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/python_programmes/hat_short.py", line 4, in <module>
    for event in sense.stick.get_events():
AttributeError: 'SenseHat' object has no attribute 'stick'
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a website called https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-accessories/blog/2017/01/23/raspberry-pi-sense-hat-enabling-the-joystick which takes you through how to make the joystick work and how to make a programme which responds to the joystick being moved, to move a dot around the screen.

To make the joy stick work, type the following into the terminal:

```
cd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sense_hat
```

then:

```
sudo rm __init__.py sense_hat.py __init__.pyc sense_hat.pyc
```

then:

```
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RPi-Distro/python-sense-hat/master/sense_hat/__init__.py   
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RPi-Distro/python-sense-hat/master/sense_hat/sense_hat.py   
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RPi-Distro/python-sense-hat/master/sense_hat/stick.py
```

then:

```
sudo nano sense_hat.py
```

then look on line 17, and the code should look like this:

```
from .stick import SenseStick
```

but you need to delete the dot, and line 17 should look like this:

```
from .stick import SenseStick
```

then you need to press ctrl+o then enter to save changes and ctrl+x to exit nano

An example of code using the joystick:

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat

sense = SenseHat()
while True:
for x in sense.stick.get_events():
    if x.direction == 'up':
        sense.show_letter("U")
    elif x.direction == 'down':
        sense.show_letter("D")
    elif x.direction == 'left':
        sense.show_letter("L")
    elif x.direction == 'right':
        sense.show_letter("R")
    elif x.direction == 'middle':
        sense.show_letter("M")
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/python-sense-hat/blob/master/sense_hat/sense_hat.py#L191), the latest version (as of June 2016) has the `stick` property on the `SenseHat` class. Make sure you have the latest `sense-hat` installed:

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade sense-hat
```

If that does not work, you can clone the repo and install it manually:

```
git clone https://github.com/RPi-Distro/python-sense-hat
cd python-sense-hat
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: I found a website which took you through some steps on how to do it. the website was:https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-accessories/blog/2017/01/23/raspberry-pi-sense-hat-enabling-the-joystick